# Wordlist transfer for an anagram program

Tags: c++, anagram

I'm almost finished with my program, but there's one last bug that I'm having problems ferreting out. The program is supposed to check about 10 scrambled words against a wordlist to see what the scrambled words are anagrams of. To do this, I alphabetized each word in the wordlist (apple would become aelpp), set that as the key of a map, and made the corresponding entry the original, unalphabetized word.

The program is messing up when it comes to the entries in the map. When the entry is six characters or less, the program tags a random character on the end of the string. I've narrowed down what can be causing the problem to a single loop:

```
while(myFile){
  myFile.getline(str, 30);
  int h=0;   
  for (; str[h] != 0; h++)//setting the initial version of str
  {
      strInit[h]=str[h]; //strInit is what becomes the entry into the map.
  }
  strInit[h+1]='\0';    //I didn't know if the for loop would include the null char
  cout<<strInit; //Personal error-checking; not necessary for the program
 }
```

And if it's necessary, here's the entire program:

[Program](http://pastebin.com/mGNd318H)

Comment: Kerrek SB: Read the whole code file, it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent issues, use normal functions:

```
getline(str, 30);
strncpy(strInit, str, 30);
```

Prevent more issues, use standard strings:

```
std::string strInit, str;
while (std::getline(myFile, str)) {
    strInit = str;
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The `ifstream` member `getline` doesn't accept a `std::string` argument.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Sorry, was confused with `std::getline`.

Comment: Thank you very much! strncpy() worked for my program. I'm not very familiar with the string commands, so perhaps I should remember to look up a list of them next time I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best not to use raw C arrays at all! Here's a version, using modern C++:

```
#include <string>

std::string str;

while (std::getline(myFile, str))
{
  // do something useful with str
  // Example: mymap[str] = f(str);
  std::cout << str; //Personal error-checking; not necessary for the program
}
```

Comment: No such thing in C-style arrays.

Comment: @nightcracker: OP didn't say he uses naked arrays

Comment: @nightcracker: You're right, I changed my post into pure C++ code.

Comment: __UGH!__ Do you even code C++? What's wrong with `strInit = str;`?